# SwiftUI is there a better way to remove background on NavigationView

Tags: uikit, swiftui, navigationview

I convinced such extension on UINavigationController to remove background making it clear on each UINavigationController all its child and parents as they also add something behind. But I think it is rather hack and it works but if apple add some other UIViewController with NavigationView with another background color then it may stop working.

```
extension UINavigationController {

    open override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        self.viewControllers.first?.view.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.view.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.parent?.view.backgroundColor = .clear
    }
}
```

Comment: with appearance you can control in which contents your view gets your desired color.